# Do I always have to unregister a broadcast receiver (and if so, how)?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I have a little app which, when started the `activity`, in the `on_create` registers a `broadcastreceiver` and then exits (by calling `finish()`)

*(side note: it surprised me that the broadcastreceiver still received the ACTION_SCREEN_OFF event, even when my app is finished. I thought the broadcastreceiver would be unregistered or so. But I the surprise was pleasant, because it was what I wanted)*

Now when the screen goes off, the `onReceive` event in the `broadcastreceiver`  goes off, and I perform my action.

Then I was wondering: Do I have to `unregister` the `broadcastreceiver` , because I only want to capture the event once, and when I don't `unregister`, won't the `broadcastreceiver` be receiving (and processing) the event until I power off the phone?

**And if so:** where do I put the `unregister` code. The app (`activity`) is gone, so I can't put it there I guess. So the only place left imo is the `broadcastreceiver`  itself, but it seems strange to `unregister` a `broadcastreceiver` in the `broadcastreceiver`  itself.

**And if not:** Why don't I have to `unregister` it?

I'm a bit lost here as you can see....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually you should register your Receiver at onStart and unRegister at onStop, or onCreate and onDestroy.  You should always unregister your receivers, especially if you only want it to be fired once. Look at your Logcat usually it informs you that you have leaked a receiver.

I dont think that your activity is gone, it might have gone trough with the lifecycle but u still keep in the memory if you are not unregistering the receiver, i think that u caused a memory leak.

Comment: Hmm, that is not the conclusion I wanted to hear ;-) Any solution?

Comment: You say "You should always unregister your receivers, especially if you only want it to be fired once". So the receiver will continue to react to events until deregistered?

Comment: Yes. Unless the system cleared your activity and then it will fire the log